# Python Output: "Not Found"

Tags: python

Using the below codes:
What do I need to add to add the below scenario:
Input: `vlookup(“001-999999-999”, user_list, 3)` Output: `“Not found”`

```
def finder(lookupvalue,lookuplist,col_index):
    user_list = [
        ["Account number","Currency","Balance"],
        ["001-987654-003","USD",1300.72],
        ["001-919202-100","EUR",105.01],
        ["001-905700-100","EUR",305.00],
        ["001-908415-307","CHF",20804.98],
        ["011-974777-200","PLN",208.15],
        ["001-931654-001","USD",450.7]
    ]

    column=len(user_list[0])
    errormsg='Out of range'

    if col_index>3:
        raise ValueError(errormsg)
    
    for row in user_list: #for every row in the list
        if row[0]==lookupvalue: #if index 0 of n row is equal to lookupvalue
            print(row[col_index-1]) #look up  and print based on the index number. Less 1 will translate to Python language
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
user_list = [
        ["Account number","Currency","Balance"],
        ["001-987654-003","USD",1300.72],
        ["001-919202-100","EUR",105.01],
        ["001-905700-100","EUR",305.00],
        ["001-908415-307","CHF",20804.98],
        ["011-974777-200","PLN",208.15],
        ["001-931654-001","USD",450.7]
    ]


    
def finder(lookupvalue,lookuplist,col_index):
    column=len(user_list[0])
    errormsg='Out of range'

    if col_index>3:
        raise ValueError(errormsg)

    count = 0
    for row in user_list: #for every row in the list
        if row[0]==lookupvalue: #if index 0 of n row is equal to lookupvalue
            print(row[col_index-1]) #look up  and print based on the index number. Less 1 will translate to Python language
            count += 1

    if not count:
        print("Not found")
finder('001-999999-999', user_list, 3)
```

Output:

```
Not found
```

Comment: can you explain pls the rationale of using the added code?

Comment: @pucktack It adds 1 to the count if there are found rows, if the count maintains to be 0, it prints `Not found`, please accept and upvote my answer as well

Comment: last question, how do i read this line: if not count:

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for a [`for-else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct, where the `else` block is executed only if the `for` loop is not aborted by a `break` statement:

```
for row in user_list:
    if row[0]==lookupvalue:
        print(row[col_index-1])
        break
else:
    print('Not Found')
```